# How can I refresh a activity from a Item<ViewHolder>() class?

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I refresh an activity from a Item() class.
I have no Idea how that should work or if it even works in that kind of class. I know how to do it inside a AppCompatActivity() class but as supposed those commands  wont work.

Thats my Item:

```
class TrackItem(val track: Track): Item<ViewHolder>() {
override fun bind(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    viewHolder.itemView.TrackName_txt.text = track.title
    viewHolder.itemView.TrackArtist_txt.text = track.artist
    viewHolder.itemView.TrackDuration_txt.text = track.duration
    Picasso.get().load(track.imageUrl).into(viewHolder.itemView.TrackImage_View)


    viewHolder.itemView.TrackDelete_btn.setOnClickListener {

        val playlistname = track.playlistId
        val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid
        val FileId = track.FileId
        val databaseref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/playlist/$uid/$playlistname/music/$FileId")
        databaseref.removeValue()
        val mp3ref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(track.trackUrl)
        mp3ref.delete()
        val coverref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(track.imageUrl)
        coverref.delete()

        recreate()


    }
}

override fun getLayout(): Int {
    return R.layout.trackinfo
}
}
```

Comment: Why you need to refresh activity from a viewholder?

Comment: Because I want to see the result (so the track doesn't shows up anymore) after the track got deleted. I is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to run in activity some code, which could do reloading/refreshing/fetching/deleting and etc with your UI or Data, just create and provide a specifically interface. Below is an example.

```
class MyAdapter constructor(private val list: List<DataModel>, private val listener: UpdateActivityListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_item_title, parent, false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = list.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemView.title.text = list[position].title
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        init {
            // Example of listener for your actions inside item
            view.setOnClickListener {
                listener.eventFirst()
            }
            view.setOnLongClickListener {
                listener.eventSecond(adapterPosition)
                true
            }
        }
    }

    // Example of callbacks which activity wait
    interface UpdateActivityListener {
        fun eventFirst()
        fun eventSecond(position: Int)
    }

}
```

Also i see that you are using some lib like FastAdapter, just refactor code and set your listener to `onBind` method. But better do it on ViewHolder init.

Comment: Thank you so much!